# Modelling population with $\frac{dP}{dt}=P(\beta - \delta P)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> The population $P(t)$ of a biological species can be modelled by
>   $$
> \frac{dP}{dt}=P(\beta - \delta P)
> $$
>   subject to $P(0)=P_0$ where $\beta$ is the birth rate and $\delta$ is the death rate. Assuming $P>0$, find the population $P(t)$ for three cases:
>
> 1. $P_0<\hat{P}$
> 2. $P_0=\hat{P}$
> 3. $P_0>\hat{P}$
>
> where $\hat{P}=^{\beta}/_{\delta}$

So far, I have:

We see the equations is separable and so
$$
\int\frac{dP}{P(\beta - \delta P)}=\int dt
$$
then in partial fractions we have
$$
\int\frac{dP}{\beta P}+\int\frac{\delta}{\beta (\beta - \delta P)}dP=\int dt
$$
integrating both sides
$$
\frac{1}{\beta}\ln P+\frac{\delta}{\beta}\ln(\beta - \delta P)=t + k
$$
$$
\ln P+\delta\ln(\beta - \delta P)=\beta t + k
$$
$$
P\cdot(\beta - \delta P)^\delta=ke^{\beta t}
$$
so at $t=0$ we have
$$
P_0\cdot(\beta - \delta P_0)^\delta=k
$$
hence
$$
P\cdot(\beta - \delta P)^\delta=P_0\cdot(\beta - \delta P_0)^\delta\cdot e^{\beta t}
$$

I don't really see how to apply the three cases to this equation; I mean it seems that $P_0=\hat{P}$ would mean $P(t)$ is identically 0 but I don't think this makes any sense in terms of the original problem. So my reasoning must be wrong..? And for the other two cases I don't see how I would express $P(t)$ generally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However, writing the solution as
$$
P(t) = \frac{\beta}{\delta}\frac{1}{1-\frac{P_0-\frac{\beta}{\delta}}{P_0}\mathrm{e}^{-\beta t}}
$$
It should be clear what happens to the solution

$\textbf{update}$
$$
\int \frac{dP}{P\left(\frac{\beta}{\delta} - P\right)} = \int \delta dt =\delta t + \lambda
$$
integrals of the form
$$
\int \frac{dx}{x(b-x)} = \frac{\ln x - \ln (x-b)}{b} 
$$
thus the integral becomes
$$
\frac{1}{\frac{\beta}{\delta}}\ln\left(\frac{P}{P - \frac{\beta}{\delta}}\right) = \delta t + \lambda\\
\frac{P}{P - \frac{\beta}{\delta}} = \mathrm{e}^{\frac{\beta}{\delta}\left(\delta t + \lambda\right)} = A\mathrm{e}^{\beta t} 
$$
I.C leasd to
$$
\frac{P_0}{P_0 - \frac{\beta}{\delta}} = A
$$
re-arranging leads to the first equation.

$\textbf{Note that I had sign wrong in the first equation which has been rectified}$

Comment: Ok. But I don't see how to derive this equation from the one above.