# Differential equation problem. Integrating the logistic equation.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to know how to integrate or rather solve this:

$$ \frac{dP}{dt} = kP(L-P). $$

I have the solution, but I would like to know how to arrive at it. 
I have been told it involves separation of variables and partial fractions.

Comment: is $P=P(t)$ and $k$ and $L$ are constants?

Comment: Check [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1060942/modelling-population-with-fracdpdt-p-beta-delta-p/1061041#1061041) out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint/Nudge:
$$\frac{dP}{dt} = kP(L-P)$$$$\iff \frac{1}{P(L-P)}dP=kdt$$
This is the seperation of variables bit. Everything that depends on $P$ is on the LHS and everything else on the RHS.

Now, do partial fractions with $\frac{1}{P(L-P)}$ on LHS and integrate.

Edit:
You are almost right. You should have $\ln P-\ln (L-P)=L(kt+c)$, from here you just need to rearrange for P. (Note that you don't need constants of integration on both sides as they can just amalgamate into one (by addition/subtraction)).

From here you exponentiate both sides to get: $$\exp(\ln P-\ln (L-P))=\exp\ln(\frac{P}{L-P})=\frac{P}{L-P}=\exp (L(kt+c))$$
Which gives, $$P=(L-P)\exp (L(kt+c))$$
and then, $$P+P\exp(L(kt+c))=P(1+\exp(L(kt+c)))=L\exp(L(kt+c))$$
finally, $$P=\frac{L\exp(L(kt+c))}{1+\exp(L(kt+c))}=L\frac{1}{1+\exp(-L(kt+c))}.$$
Tidy this up by defining $A=\exp(-Lc)$ which gives your general solution as:
$$P=L\frac{1}{1+Ae^{-Lkt}}.$$

Comment: I get lnP - ln(L-P) + c = kt + c. i'm a little bit stuck!

Comment: I'll add to the answer

Comment: Even if L is a constant?. i cant't believe i am still having problems, you guys have practically walked me thought it!

Comment: I have assumed L is a constant here.

Comment: omg its finally clicked. thanks. so much!

Answer (score 0):

you will get
$$-{\frac {\ln  \left( L-P \right) }{L}}+{\frac {\ln  \left( P \right) 
}{L}}
=kt+C$$